# Unable to remove invisible chars using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, chars

I want to remove any invisible chars from a string, only keep spaces & any chars from 0x20-0x7F,
I use this: `Regex.Replace(QueryString, @"[^\s\x20-\x7F]", "");`
However it does not work

`QueryString` has a char 0xA0, after that, the char still exists in `QueryString`.

I am not sure why this failed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xA0` is the non-breaking space character - and as such it's matched with `\s`.  Rather than using `\s`, expand this out into the list of whitespace characters you want to include.

Comment: thanks you so much, Will A. that works. I do not know how to mark as answer?

Comment: My pleasure - happy regex'ing!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would rather use StringBuilder to process such strings.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
foreach(char ch in str)
{
    if (0x20 <= ch && ch <= 0x7F)
    {
        sb.Append(ch)
    }
}

string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks, oxilumin. I will mark yours as helpful once I restore my login info.